# z-index issue when placing text over images

Tags: html, css

I'll provide CSS and HTML sources first.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TCKH5/)

[The live example is here](http://www.sobafire.com/__v2/)

The problem is, `h2` texts are not visible unless I do `z-index: -1;` on `images`. It makes the text appear, however, then the image is being lost and I look at `body background`.

There is not something touching `z-index` values except the fixed navigation bar at top.

What may be causing this, can you have a look?

Ps. Writing `z-index: 2;` on `H2` tags doesn't work either.

Comment: images have "position: absolute" and this is why they hide the text.

Comment: Read this article too http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want `z-index:2` on `<h2>` works, you should add `position:relative;` or `position:absolute;` or `position:fixed`.

You can see [`z-index`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

Answer (score 0):

i change your HTML & CSS

change in HTML: Move **img** into **a** tag

```
 <div class="spotlight-area">
    <div class="spotlight">

            <div class="spotlight-item width-2 height-2">
                <a href="#" class="spotlight-info">
                    <h2 class="large">
                        Random text
                    </h2>
                    <img src="http://www.sobafire.com/__v2/themes/default/images/news/spotlight-big.jpg" alt="haber">
                </a>


            </div>

            <div class="spotlight-item width-1 height-1">
                <a href="#" class="spotlight-info">
                    <h2>
                        Random Text
                    </h2>
                </a>

                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/TAxDMus.jpg" alt="haber">
            </div>

            <div class="spotlight-item width-1 height-1">
                <a href="#" class="spotlight-info">
                    <h2>
                        Random Text
                    </h2>
                    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/TAxDMus.jpg" alt="haber">
                </a>


            </div>

            <div class="spotlight-item width-1 height-1">
                <a href="#" class="spotlight-info">
                    <h2>
                        Random Text
                    </h2>
                    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/TAxDMus.jpg" alt="haber">
                </a>


            </div>

            <div class="spotlight-item width-1 height-1">
                <a href="#" class="spotlight-info">
                    <h2>
                        Random Text
                    </h2>
                    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/TAxDMus.jpg" alt="haber">
                </a>


            </div>

            <div class="spotlight-item width-1 height-1">
                <a href="#" class="spotlight-info">
                    <h2>
                        Random Text
                    </h2>
                    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/TAxDMus.jpg" alt="haber">
                </a>


            </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

css:

change On CSS: Remove **position: absolute;** From **img** and ADD It TO **.spotlight-area .spotlight .spotlight-item:hover .spotlight-info h2** Remove **padding** From **.spotlight-area .spotlight-info {** and Add **Margin** to **.spotlight-area .spotlight .spotlight-item:hover .spotlight-info h2** with similar value

```
.spotlight-area {
width: 790px;
margin: 0px auto;
padding: 0px;
}
.spotlight-area img, .spotlight-area embed {
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
min-height: 50px;
}

.spotlight-area .spotlight {
display: block;
border-top: 1px solid #3b3b3b;
border-left: 1px solid #3b3b3b;
float: left;
margin-bottom: 4px;
}

.spotlight-area .spotlight .width-1 { width: 262px }
.spotlight-area .spotlight .width-2 { width: 525px }
.spotlight-area .spotlight .height-1 { height: 174px }
.spotlight-area .spotlight .height-2 { height: 349px }
.spotlight-area .spotlight .spotlight-item {
float: left;
position: relative;
border-bottom: 1px solid #3b3b3b;
border-right: 1px solid #3b3b3b;
overflow: hidden;
 }

 .spotlight-area .spotlight .spotlight-item:hover .spotlight-info h2 {
color: #ffc203;
 }
 .spotlight-area .spotlight .spotlight-item img {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;

top: 0;
left: 0;
margin: 0;
border: 0;
    z-index: -1; /* tricky part */
}

.spotlight-area .spotlight-info {
display: block;
height: 100%;
min-height: 50px;
}

.spotlight-area .spotlight-info a {
display: block;
height: 100%;
min-height: 50px;
padding: 20px;
}

.spotlight-area .spotlight .spotlight-item .spotlight-info h2 {
display: inline-block;
max-width: 480px;
font-size: 30px;
line-height: 32px;
color: #f0f0f0;
    position: absolute;
    margin:20px;
}
```

in My Test This Change work

Comment: What changes did you make?

Comment: @LyverKinkki I wrote change on answer